# How can I loop through a list and for each distinct value initiate another loop?

Tags: python

I have a python list, this list is of any document that has been updated within a set timeframe and the documents are ID'd via a set value in the list.  There may be one or many in the resulting list.  What I am trying to figure out is how I can loop through the list of values (documents) and trigger another loop that iterates through another list I have of emails resulting in one email per address per document in the original list?  I tried to "stack" loops on top of each other (code snippet shown below), but this results in multiple emails to each email address all with a full list of documents (i.e. if there are two documents in the list, two emails are sent to each address with the details about both documents).

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#first get request to pull all current endusers
GET1 = "https://abdc.com/api"

r1 = requests.get(url = GET1, auth=('username/token','APItoken'))

#convert to python dict
data = r1.json()

#create a list of all user's email addresses
emails = [user["email"] for user in data["users"]]

#create an timestamp of previous day and convert to epoch
ts1 = datetime.today() - timedelta(days =1)
ts2 = ts1.strftime("%s")

#set start time attribute as a parameter
params = {'start_time':ts2}

#second GET reqeust to pull all articles updated in the last 24 hrs
GET2 = "https://efdg.com/api"

r2 = requests.get(url = GET2, params=params, auth=('username/token','APItoken'))

#convert to python dict
data2 = r2.json()

#create list of all the target article titles and html url
updated_docs = [articles["html_url"] for articles in data2["articles"]]
doc_title = [articles["title"] for articles in data2["articles"]]

for y in updated_doc:

   #create loop to iterate throuhg all the email addresses and send 
   individual emails to users
   for x in emails:
        # This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
        SENDER = "example@example.com"

        #To list
        RECIPIENT = x

        # Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
        # set, comment the following variable, and the
        # ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
        #CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

        # If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
        AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"

        # The subject line for the email.
        SUBJECT = "blah blah "

        # The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
        BODY_TEXT = ("Amazon SES Test (Python)\r\n"
                     "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the "
                     "AWS SDK for Python (Boto)."
                     )

        # The HTML body of the email.
        BODY_HTML = """<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <h1>l Documentation Notification</h1>
          <p1>Please click the link below for the most current version of this document.<br>
          <br>
          """+str(doc_title)+"""<br>
          <br>
          """+str(updated_docs)+"""
          </p1>
        </body>
        </html>
                    """

        # The character encoding for the email.
        CHARSET = "UTF-8"

        # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
        client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=AWS_REGION)

        # Try to send the email.
        try:
            # Provide the contents of the email.
            response = client.send_email(
                Destination={
                    'ToAddresses': [
                        RECIPIENT,
                    ],
                },
                Message={
                    'Body': {
                        'Html': {
                            'Charset': CHARSET,
                            'Data': BODY_HTML,
                        },
                        'Text': {
                            'Charset': CHARSET,
                            'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                        },
                    },
                    'Subject': {
                        'Charset': CHARSET,
                        'Data': SUBJECT,
                    },
                },
                Source=SENDER,
                # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
                # following line
                #ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
            )
        # Display an error if something goes wrong.
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
            print(response['MessageId'])
```

Comment: So, why do you want to iterate through the documents? What do you want to be present in each email?

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample/dummy data? Also, what are you trying to achieve with your loops?

Comment: @quamrana As during the set time frame multiple documents may be updated, I need to send an email out for all documents in the list containing the title and url.  Both of which I get from the list (which originates from a GET request).  As I mentioned my code works except if there are more than one document, the email contains details for all documents.  Its a one to many relationship now but I want a one to one relationship....one email per email address per document in the list

Comment: Do you mean you want one email per email address, which lists every document in the list?

Comment: no, I want to send one email per document in the list to each email address.  so if there are two documents in the list each recipient would receive one email per document for a total of two

Comment: How do you compose an email now? You don't show any of those details in your code.

Comment: I am using Amazon SES python SDK to send out the emails.  I did not think that part was relevant to the issue I was facing as the code to send the emails only accepts the arguments of 'recipients' and message content as pass with the variables 'html_url' and 'title'

Comment: Please show these details. All we can deduce currently is that each email address gets multiple emails.

Comment: sorry...added full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've completely changed your code, so I'm well confused, but if I can read between the lines properly you meant something like this:

```py
#create loop to iterate through all documents in the list
for article in data2["articles"]:

    #create loop to iterate through all the email addresses and send individual emails to 
    users
    for x in emails:
        # This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
        SENDER = "example@example.com"

        #To list
        RECIPIENT = x

        # The HTML body of the email.
        BODY_HTML = """<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <h1>l Documentation Notification</h1>
          <p1>Please click the link below for the most current version of this document.<br>
          <br>
          """+str(article["title"])+"""<br>
          <br>
          """+str(article["html_url"])+"""
          </p1>
        </body>
        </html>
                    """
```

Notice how I iterate through `data2["articles"]` and update the `BODY_HTML` with `article["title"]` and `article["html_url"]`,

Comment: That did it!  I now get one to one relationship between document and email